# When passing through SSL from web server A to web server B (via nginx), does web server A need SSL configured as well, or just web server B?

Tags: tls, http, tcp, nginx

I'm using nginx here as an example, but this is really more of a conceptual question about SSL termination and TCP that could apply to any web server.

Basically, if web server A receives TCP traffic on port 443 (the first nginx config) and then forwards that to web server B on port 1000 running HTTPS (the second nginx config), do I need to even have SSL configured for web server A?

As far as I understand, the answer is no, because web server A is ultimately just forwarding the encrypted traffic it gets on 443 "as is" to port 1000 to be decrypted by web server B. Basically:

`client -> encrypted traffic -> web server A -> Pass through (encrypted) -> web server B -> decrypted traffic`

However, on the first connection, does it matter than the traffic is temporarily unencrypted, as it routes through web server A before the SSL handshake is established. I've never had a setup where the client establishes an SSL connection to web server B via TCP over web server A, which is not encrypted, so I'm not sure if that is secure. I think it's still fine, as the SSL handshake itself occurs over an unencrypted TCP connection, but not quite sure.

```
events {}
stream {
    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:1250;
    }
}
```

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 1000 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:1000 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/foo.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/foo.pem;
   
        # App

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
```

Comment: I believe the reverse proxy installs the site's cert (the DNS record points to it).... for server-a to server b you use whatever cert you like but not the site cert as it wouldn't be valid for that domain.

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct.  Web server A is simply routing TCP packets to web server B,  In that regard, server a is simply acting as a router.  You could do the same thing, for that matter, using `iptables` instead of nginx on server a.  Therefore, there is no need to setup SSL on web server A. WRT `on the first connection, does it matter than the traffic is temporarily unencrypted` - no.  The initial (unencrypted) handshake passing through server a is no different than the initial unencrypted handshake passing through numerous routers when you connect directly to any HTTPS site.

Comment: @mti2935 that makes sense to me, thanks so much for the confirmation and explanation!

Comment: @mti2935 You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Marcel.   But, I would basically just be re-posting what I've already written, so I'll just leave it as is.